# Return rows where specific column has duplicate values

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, having-clause

From the table below I want to show the two rows where the values in column 3 are duplicates:

| ID | Col2 | Col3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | a | 123 |
| 2 | b | 123 |
| 3 | c | 14 |
| 4 | d | 65 |
| 5 | e | 65 |

This means that the query that I need should return rows with ID 1, 2 and 4, 5.
I wrote query using `having`:

```
SELECT *
FROM t1
INNER JOIN (SELECT col3 FROM t1
            GROUP BY col3
            HAVING COUNT(*) > 1) a
ON t1.col3 = a.col3
```

This query though only returns 1 and 4 rows for example, not all duplicates.
I would appreciate the help.

Comment: Your query should work.  If `col3` is stored as a string, perhaps there are hidden or look-alike characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query should work, but I would suggest window functions:

```
select t1.*
from (select t1.*, count(*) over (partition by col3) as cnt
      from t1
     ) t1
where cnt > 1;
```

Comment: Thank you. You are right, it is working, I just had added some additional clause that limited my results and got frustrated. But what would you suggest is better, my approach or this window function?

Comment: @Yana . . . Window functions are usually faster -- they are built-in and the database is optimized for them.

Comment: Thank you. I will have to practice using them.

Comment: If it's just finding dupes, I usually use exists, I would think that would be faster than windowing since it short circuits?

Comment: @AnthonyHancock . . . I think `EXISTS` with appropriate indexes is generally faster than window functions for the specific purpose of finding duplicates.